# Times represents different on different servers

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php and I have an issue with time representing differently on my test vr production servers. I'm doing a calculation of hour worked, like on a time clock. Punch in to punch out = total hour worked. I'm using this code:

```
$time1 = $_POST['txt_starttime'];
$time2= $_POST['txt_endtime'];

$TotTime=date('H:i',strtotime($time2)-strtotime($time1));
```

11:45 PM to 11:50 PM = 5 minutes  On my test server it works fine and stores 00:05 in the db. On the production server it's giving me 05:05:00  I played with the format variables but then I get 17:05:00

Is this a server side setting... help please!!!

Comment: +1'd because someone downvoted without telling why. PLEASE stop doing that people, knowing our mistakes is how we learn. In addidtion, I imagine the reason he downvoted is because you didnt edit your question properly, when you use code in a question, try to use the code format stackoverflow offers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the time zone

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+1');
```

Comment: I found a way to correct the time/server by adding seconds:

$tot_hours_1 = date('H:i',strtotime($etime_1)-strtotime($time_1)+25200);

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the server is using the default GMT TimeZone. You need to match the difference in your logic or configure your server to adjust the difference.

So, if your home Time Zone is `+530` hours, you need to add `+ 5 hours 30 minutes` to the `strtotime()`, in a way, like:

```
if ($production)
    $basetime = "+ 5 hours 30 minutes";
else
    $basetime = ""
```

And you need to set the flag in the production to `true`.

Else, you can make use of the function [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and passing the timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

Answer (score 0):

`date` gives you a **time of day** from a UNIX timestamp. A UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1st 1970; thereby it is a *relative time*. The result of `date` is an *absolute time*.

You want to represent a time span, i.e. *relative time*. Don't format it into an absolute time. What you're producing is the absolute timestamp *January 1st 1970 00:05*, the hour and minute part of which happen to be `00:05` if represented in the right timezone. In a different timezone, it will be different.

To go from `300` (seconds) to `5` (minutes), convert them using math (`300 / 60`).